# How to take integers being printed by a method?

Tags: java, methods, random, blackjack

I am making a very simple blackjack game with one class and at least 2 methods. I want to take the random generated numbers that are being output (cards being dealt) and add them so I can make an if else statement to check if the total is over 21 causing the player to lose.

```
import java.util.*;

public class BlackJack {

    private Scanner scan;
    static Random generator = new Random();

    public BlackJack(){
        scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StarterCards();
        Hit();
    }

    public static void Hit() {
        System.out.println("Hit? (y or n)");
        String yes = new String ("y");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yesorno = input.nextLine();
        if(yesorno.equals(yes)) {
            RandomCard();
            Hit();
            if()
            } else {
                System.out.println("Game Over");
            }   
    }

    public static void RandomCard() {
        int card = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.println("Card : "+ card);
        int total2 = card;
    }

    public static void StarterCards() {
        int card1 = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int card2 = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.println("Card : "+ card1);
        System.out.println("Card : "+ card2);
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @JBNizet *"How to take integers being printed by a method?"*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Re:

> How to take integers being printed by a method?

The solution: don't have the method print anything. Instead have the method ***return*** the number, and let the calling code print it or do with the number whatever it wants to do.

i.e.,

```
public int myMethod() {
   int someNumber = ....; // calculate it here
   // System.out.println(someNumber);  // don't print it here!
   return someNumber
}
```

Comment: @user3029889: nope, you're learning Java. None of us was born knowing this chit.

Comment: If I'm using the random generator, how do I add up each of the numbers that are printed? If I call the method wont it just give me different numbers?

Comment: @user3029889: yep, it will give you different numbers. Then the calling code, the code that calls this method, can print out the number and add it to a sum variable.